# tikz align nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

is it possible with TikZ to align a new node with respect to existing ones? I know the answer is affirmative in the case of one node using e.g. the node coordinate system, but what about align with respect to two nodes?

Example: suppose there are two nodes defined (A) and (B) and I want to create a third node (C) such that xy-coordinates satisfy C.x = A.x and C.y = B.y i.e. node (C) is vertically aligned with (B) and horizontally aligned with (A).

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code (with both cases mentioned), starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this using `|-` and `-|` along with `node[midway]`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node (B) at (8,3) {B};
    \path (A) |- (B) node[midway] (C) {C};
    \path (A) -| (B) node[midway] (D) {D};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! However looking at the -|  and |- operators I found a shortcut in the manual which is the perpendicular coordinate system. One only needs to define `\node (C) at (A -| B) {C};`.